# How to add current year to a given date and month

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date as input in the format - `"Nov 24 - Nov 25"`.
I need the dates to be split as follow.

```
FromDate - '24-NOV-2017'
ToDate   - '25-NOV-2017'
```

I am unable to understand how to append the *current year* .
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you put in the code?

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be an edit too. Your attempts should be turned into a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: Write some codes as follows and tell what is not right: split string, parse date from string according date format

Answer (score 2):

`Split` and then [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string source = "Nov 24 - Nov 25";

DateTime[] dates = source
  .Split('-')
  .Select(item => DateTime.ParseExact(
     item.Trim(), 
    "MMM d", // Month (abbreviated), day; the year is current
     CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")))
  .ToArray(); 

DateTime fromDate = dates[0];
DateTime toDate = dates[1]; 

Console.WriteLine($"FromDate - '{fromDate:dd'-'MMM'-'yyyy}' ToDate - '{toDate:dd'-'MMM'-'yyyy}'");
```

Outcome:

```
  FromDate - '24-Nov-2017' ToDate - '25-Nov-2017'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below:

```
FromDate.ToString("dd , MMMM , yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple method :

```
public string[] myDate(string date, string year)
    {
        string date1 = date.Split('-')[0];
        string date2 = date.Split('-')[1];
        string[] dateSplit1 = date1.Split();
        string[] dateSplit2 = date2.Split();
        return new string[] { dateSplit1[1] + "-" + dateSplit1[0].ToUpper() + "-" + year, dateSplit2[2] + "-" + dateSplit2[1].ToUpper() + "-" + year };
    }
```

The method input in your case would be:

```
string[] Dates = myDate("Nov 24 - Nov 25","2017")
```

The method returns a string array with your desired dates:

Date[0] contains "24-NOV-2017" and Date [1] contains "25-NOV-2017"